# update a contact email addresses

Tags: android

I can update a google contact (home) email with the following statement:

```
    String select = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"  +
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE + "=?";     
    String[] args = new String[]{m_sID, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)};      
    m_ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)             
            .withSelection(select, args)             
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, "xxxxx@xxxx.com")             
            .build());
```

But how can I update a phone book contacts different email addresses?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use TYPE_WORK, TYPE_OTHER or TYPE_MOBILE instead of TYPE_HOME, depending on which one you want to update.
You can also use TYPE_CUSTOM, but you should then add

```
+ " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.LABEL + "=?"
```

to your select and the desired label to your args.

Comment: Thanks Martin, it was LABEL is was looking for. But it's always null in my desire. Any ideas?

Comment: IIRC, the label is set only for the TYPE_CUSTOM. It's always null for the others TYPE_XXX.

Answer (score 0):

The only email filer condition that you have applied is for email with type HOME. **ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME** which needs to be removed
i.e dont apply the filter ***" AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE + "=?"***